# How do I get an Asp.Net radiobox to callback when it is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net/C# application, and trying to get a radiobox to invoke a callback when any of the buttons on it is clicked. Does anyone know how to do this? I've tried this...

```
<asp:RadioButton id="id1" onclick="do_foo" runat="server" Text="Text1" GroupName="mybox" />
<asp:RadioButton id="id2" onclick="do_foo" runat="server" Text="Text2" GroupName="mybox" />
<asp:RadioButton id="id3" onclick="do_foo" runat="server" Text="Text3" GroupName="mybox" />
```

and also this...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList onclick="do_foo" id="radiolist1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Text1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Text2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Text3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

but in both cases get the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'do_foo' is undefined". I know that do_foo is defined because I can invoke it from a button.

Comment: have you tried onclick="javascript:do_foo();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>text1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>text2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>text3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
onclick="do_foo();"
```

Tested without the brackets and it doesn't fire.

Comment: Thank you; so I need `();` if the function is Javascript, and not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Please include brackets after function name, It should like this

```
onclick="do_foo();"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaking Javascript client side function with a c# server side function.

Radio Buttons dont have a server side 'onclick' event but a client side exists so when it is clicked the browser cant find do_foo, hence the error.

You will have to use `AutoPostBack="True"` and the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to check which item was clicked like:

```
if(radiolist1.SelectedIndex==0) 
{
  //first item clicked
}
else if(radiolist1.SelectedIndex==1) 
{
  //second item clicked
}
```